GitHub action fails to locate firebase.json
My nest.js app can deploy to firebase locally no problem via the CLI. However, my GitHub action fails and outputs an error:

Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)

I'm confused because firebase.json is located in apps/webhook-broadcaster/firebase.json.
Here is my complete GitHub action
name: Firebase Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup pnpm
        uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        with:
          version: "8.15.4"

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "v20.8.0"
          cache: "pnpm"

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Install Nest CLI
        run: pnpm install --global @nestjs/cli

      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd apps/webhook-broadcaster
          pnpm install
          pnpm run build

      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: apps/webhook-broadcaster/dist

  deploy:
    name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: build
          path: apps/webhook-broadcaster/dist

      - name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_WEBHOOK_BROADCASTER }}


The error:
This is the GitHub action I've ever written and the first firebase app I've ever deployed. I'd love some help or guidance on this issue. Thanks!

You use cd in your build step but not in your deploy step.  I assume the error is happening during deploy and not build.

tried this, but now Error: Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login? is outputted.

Try this:
- name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting
  uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
  with:
    args: deploy —-config ./apps/webhook-broadcaster/firebase.json --only hosting
  env:
      FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_WEBHOOK_BROADCASTER }}


This produces an error: uses cannot be used with working-directory

In that case, try  using —config option - see updated answer

sorry, I don't see how you updated it. @Delta George

Not sure what happened - updated the answer again.
